# how to parse Mysql raw fields in to object in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This is mycode that get all the rows from the artical table in mysql but
i   want that to be re-presentable in object and array form so i can sent it to end pionts.

```
    app.get('/artical' , function(req , res){

     var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : 'root',
          password : 'root',
          database : 'project',
          port     : 3308
        });

       connection.query("SELECT * FROM artical",function(err,     result,rows) {
          // connected! (unless `err` is set) 
          if(!err){


                 res.render('pages/articals');
          }
          else{
            console.log(err)
          }

        });

});
```

Comment: At the very least use a layer like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) to give yourself a tiny bit of abstraction, the low-level driver isn't very friendly to work with. Secondly, your question isn't specific enough. What does "re-presentable" mean here?

Comment: re-presntable means that i want to store the sqlite data into array which has objects inside

Comment: You can store just about anything, so that term is largely meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second arguments of callback function is an array with objects. You shouldn't parse it. You can read more on official npm page of mysql module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

If you want to rename column to specific name you can do it

```
connection.query("SELECT title as TITLE, author as AUTHOR FROM article", function(err, rows) {
    rows.forEach(function (elem) { 
        console.log(elem.TITLE + ' ' + elem.AUTHOR);
    });
})
```